# Chart Service: How select with series to display

Tags: charts, google-apps-script, google-visualization

I'm creating a simple chart in order to learn how the Chart Service from Google Apps Script works. So far, here is what I've accomplished:

[Spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1x9g2N5gFCAeU6DkS-BYiB6womhsNfT3kPH2L22ZI3iM/edit#gid=973420299)

[The chart](https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbwc8RyFPJpRrqa23zdw9KorpDq6Rc1LCXS9Re3bOYON1tk8YRQ/exec)

The Code:

```
 function doGet() {
   var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1x9g2N5gFCAeU6DkS-BYiB6womhsNfT3kPH2L22ZI3iM/edit#gid=973420299");
   var sheetDados = ss.getSheetByName("Receita e Investimento");
   var lastLine = sheetDados.getLastRow();
   var dataTableValeus = sheetDados.getRange(16, 1, lastLine, 3).getValues();



   var data = Charts.newDataTable()
       .addColumn(Charts.ColumnType.DATE, "Data")
       .addColumn(Charts.ColumnType.NUMBER, "Cost")
       .addColumn(Charts.ColumnType.NUMBER, "Revenue");

   for(var linha = 0, len = dataTableValeus.length; linha < len; linha++){
     if (dataTableValeus[linha][0] != ""){
       data.addRow(dataTableValeus[linha]);
     }
   }

   data.build();


  var chart = Charts.newAreaChart()
       .setTitle("Revenue and Cost")
       .setDataTable(data)
       .setOption("vAxis.format", "currency")
       .setOption("hAxis.format", "d/MMM/yyyy")
       .setOption("legend.position", "top")
       .setOption("selectionMode", "multiple")
       .setOption("tooltip.trigger", "selection")
       .setOption("aggregationTarget", "series")
       .setDimensions(600, 300)
       .build();


  var dashboard = Charts.newDashboardPanel()
      .setDataTable(data)
      .build();


  var uiApp = UiApp.createApplication();

  dashboard.add(uiApp.createVerticalPanel()
                .add(uiApp.createHorizontalPanel()
                    .add(chart)
                    .setSpacing(10)));

  uiApp.add(dashboard);
  return uiApp;
 }
```

I want to find a way to select in the dashboard, which series appears in the Chart. I've tried filters, but it does not work.

My problem is not display one or the other or even both. My problem is the end-user being able to select which series to see. I would work sort like a filter where he would select to see in the chart one series, the other, or both.

In my example I want to select if the chart will display just "cost", just "Revenue" or both.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `dataViewDefinition` over the `dataTable`.

to show cost...

`.setDataViewDefinition({'columns': [0, 1]})`

revenue...

`.setDataViewDefinition({'columns': [0, 2]})`

Comment: Sorry... I was not specific in my question... I´ve edit it to be more precise.

Comment: do you have to use apps-script? would be easier using [Google Charts](https://developers.google.com/chart/) directly -- you need to redraw the chart, based on user selection -- have you posted all your code?

Comment: As far as I understand using Google Charts directly would mean developing everything in HTML, which would be way more complex than I`m willing to do.

Comment: i'm not familiar with google-apps-script, are you able to create dashboards as referenced [here](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/controls)? Then you could add a [category filter control](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/controls#googlevisualizationcategoryfilter). Or if you can add a button or dropdown yourself, then set the view definition based on the selection and redraw the chart...